# Spectrum in an separable Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

I'd like to comment in this post [Spectrum in an separable Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262047/spectrum-in-an-separable-hilbert-space?rq=1) because I have some doubts  but I don´t have reputation for this, so I'll ask here.

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_{i}\}$. Let ($c_{n}$) be a bounded sequence of real numbers and consider the bounded linear operator $T$ on $H$ defined by
$Tx=∑_{n≥1} c_{n}(e_{n},x)e_{n}$.

Prove that "The spectrum is the closure of the set $\{c_{n},n⩾1\}$", i.e,  $\overline{\{c_{n},n⩾1\}} = \sigma(T)$

Note that $\{c_{n},n⩾1\}$ is a set of eigenvalues

$(\subseteq)$ It´s clear that  $\overline{\{c_{n},n⩾1\}} \subseteq \sigma(T)$, because $\sigma(T)$ contains the set of eigenvalues and $\sigma(T)$ is compact, thus closed and bounded.

$(\supseteq)$ Let $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$ such that $\lambda \notin \{c_{n},n⩾1\}$. So $Ker(T-\lambda I ) = \{0\}$ and $T-\lambda I$ isn´t surjective.  By $Ker(T-\lambda I ) = \{0\}$ we can show that $\{e_{i}\}_{i\geq 1} \subseteq (T-\lambda I)(H)$, so $\overline{(T-\lambda I)(H)} = H$.

**Statement** If  $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$ such that $\lambda \notin \{c_{n},n⩾1\}$, so $Ker(T-\lambda I ) = \{0\}$

If  $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$ such that $\lambda  \notin \{c_{n},n \geq 1 \}$. We have that $(T - \lambda I)$ is not bijective.

Suppose by contradiction that $Ker(T - \lambda I) \neq 0$, we that $\lambda $  is eigenvalue,

so $\exists x \in H\setminus \{0\}$ such that $T(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} x_{j}e_{j}c_{j} = \lambda x =  \sum_{n \geq 1}  \lambda x_{j}e_{j}$

We have that $\sum_{n \geq 1} x_{j}e_{j}c_{j} -   \lambda x_{j}e_{j} = 0= \sum_{n \geq 1} x_{j}e_{j}(c_{j} -   \lambda)$, hence

$\sum_{n \geq 1} |x_{j}e_{j}(c_{j} -   \lambda)|^{2} = \sum_{n \geq 1} |x_{j}|^{2}|(c_{j} -   \lambda)|^{2}  = 0$, but $x \neq 0$, so $\exists x_{k} \neq 0$, remark that $\lambda  \notin \{c_{n},n \geq 1 \}$, so $\lambda \neq c_{k}$

Thus  $|x_{k}|^{2}|(c_{k} -   \lambda)|^{2} > 0$, but $\sum_{n \geq 1} |x_{j}|^{2}|(c_{j} -   \lambda)|^{2}  = 0$, it´s a contradiction, and the **statement** is proved.

We have that  $(T - \lambda I)$ is not bijective and $Ker(T-\lambda I ) = \{0\}$, so $T-\lambda I$ isn´t surjective.

Suppose by contradiction that $\lambda \notin \overline{\{c_{n},n⩾1\}}$ so there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $n$, $|\lambda−c_{n}|>\delta$...

Why is it a problem? I didn´t see the contradiction.

Thank you

Comment: how do you know $Ker(T-\lambda I) = \{ 0 \}$  if $\lambda \ne c_n$ for every $n$ ? you need at least $c_n \ne 0$ for every $c_n$, or restraining $T$ to the  correct subspace. so if $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n \to 0$ is $T$ invertible ? what if $c_n \to a$, is $T - a I$ invertible ?

Comment: @user1952009 I put a  statement in question  to answer this.

Comment: sorry, you are right $Ker(T-\lambda I) = \{0\}$ iff $\lambda \not \in \{c_n\}$ because for every $e_n$, $c_n \ne \lambda$ so $T \frac{e_n}{c_n-\lambda} = e_n$, hence $(T-\lambda I)u \ne 0$ except for $u= 0$. but this doesn't mean $T-\lambda I$ is inversible (i.e. its inverse is bounded ?).  for $T-\lambda I$ to be bounded you need $\min |c_n-\lambda| > \epsilon$ i.e. $\lambda \not \in \overline{\{c_n\}} = \sigma(T)$ by definition.

Comment: [wikipedia says the spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)#Definition) is the set of $\lambda$ such that $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is not a **bounded** linear operator. is it what you missed ? and  still didn't understand the end of your post, what you'd like to prove or where is the contradiciton

Comment: @user1952009 Yes,the $T - \lambda I$ is not inversible (I didn´t say it), because  $T - \lambda I$ is not surjective.  In this question, I want to show this: "$\overline{\{c_{n}\}} = \sigma(T)$". So, I suppose by contradiction that $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$ and  $\lambda \notin \overline{\{c_{n}\}}$, so $\lambda \notin  \{c_{n}\}$... but I don´t know to where I can  go  now... Some hunt?

Comment: if $\lambda \not \in \overline{\{c_n\}}$ then $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is $u \to \displaystyle\sum_n \frac{\langle e_n,u\rangle e_n}{c_n -\lambda}$  and its (operator) norm is $\frac{1}{\min_n |c_n-\lambda|} < \infty$ so $\lambda \not\in \sigma(T)$

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you